# Firebase Firestore Getting specific fields from my document flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get some fields in my firestore collection/document. I want to display them in some places in my code.

How can i get a particular field, like maybe phoneNumber from the user's field in the document/collection.

THis is how the user's data gets stored in the firebase.

//create UsersCollection data (First level verification) == Users Profile

```
Future createUserData(
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String emailAddress,
    String phoneNumber,
    String gender
  ) async{
    return getInstance.collection("users").doc(user!.email)
      .collection("User Profile").doc(uid).set({
        "firstName" : firstName,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "emailAddress" : emailAddress,
        "phoneNumber" : phoneNumber,
        "gender" : gender
      });
  }
```

How can I get the phonenUmber maybe. Or even the firstName.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from firebase you can try multiple ways

For fetching single item

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
var docSnapshot = await collection.doc('documentIdhere').get();
if (docSnapshot.exists) {
  Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
  var value = data?['firstName']; // gets the first name
 setState((){});
}
```

You can also use a future builder like this

```dart
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  future: collection.doc('docume tIdHere').get(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text ('${snapshot.error}');

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var data = snapshot.data!.data();
      var firstName = data!['firstName']; 
      return Text('first name is $firstName');
    }

    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
)
```

Comment: What I want to get is nested in a subcollection. I will share what I have tried but it keeps showing "Instance of Future<dynamic>"

Comment: phoneNumber() async {
    final usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.email).collection("User Profile");
    DocumentSnapshot serchUser = await usersCol.doc("profile").get();
    String phoneNumber = serchUser.get("phoneNumber");
    return phoneNumber;
  }

Comment: This is what Ive written

Comment: phoneNumber() async { final usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.email).collection("User Profile").get(); you missed the get

Comment: What I want to get is from the doc"profile". Which is why I called serchUser = await...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method and store the result in list

```
List myListOfValue[];

List myListOfElement[];


CollectionReference deliveryList =
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your Collecetion');

getData() async {

      await deliveryList.get().then((value) {
        for (var element in value.docs) {
          // you can get a specific value
          myListOfValue.add(element['your Value in FireStore']);
          // or you can get the entire element and get the value inside the 
           //element later
          myListOfElement.add(element);
       
        }
      });}
```